# Bash Scripting: How to check if there's is only one root id?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, audit

How do I edit my script so that it checks that there is only one root ID?

**Expected Output**

```
Audit criteria: There is only one root id

Vulnerability: Yes

Details: See below


root:!:0:0::/:/usr/bin/bash

jdoe:*:0:1:John Doe:/home/jdoe:/usr/bin/bash
```

**The Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

isVulnerable="No"
isVulnerable="Yes"    

cat /etc/passwd | cut -f3 -d":" | sort -n | /usr/bin/uniq -c | while read x ;            
do 
   [ -z "${x}" ] && break
   set - $x

if [ "$1" -gt 1 ]; then
    users=`/bin/gawk -F: '($3 == n) { print $1 }' n=$2 /etc/passwd | /usr/bin/xargs`

echo "Audit Criteria: Duplicate UID ($2): ${users}"
echo "Vulnerability: ${isVulnerable}"
echo "Details: see below"
echo
grep "x:0:" /etc/passwd

else

echo "All user id are unique"
fi

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite convenient to collect the rows with duplicate fields using AWK:

```
get_dups() {
  awk -F':' '$3 == 0 { if (dup++) print } END { exit(dup > 1) }' /etc/passwd
}
```

If there are multiple zero user IDs in `/etc/passwd` file, the function exits with non-zero status, and prints the lines having duplicate root user IDs to the standard output. Otherwise, the exit status is zero.

Usage:

```
dups="$(get_dups)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  vulnerability='No'
  msg='There is only one root ID'
else
  vulnerability='Yes'
  msg='There are multiple root IDs'
fi
printf '%15s: %s\n' 'Audit criteria' "$msg"
printf '%15s: %s\n' 'Vulnerability' "$vulnerability"

[ -z "$dups" ] && dups='All user IDs are unique'
printf '\n%s\n' "$dups"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
ROOT_COUNT=$(cut -f3 -d":" </etc/passwd | grep -c ^0$)
```

Then, if `ROOT_COUNT` contains something higher than 1, you have multiple users with UID 0.

Comment: or `grep -c` instead of `wc -l`. Or you could replace the entire pipeline with a tiny awk script.

Comment: @ghoti I updated my answer, never noticed this grep option before.  Thanks!